# IPv4 settings in Fritz!box and clients for private VPN

Tags: vpn, ipv4, fritzbox

I'd like to set up a VPN from an android device and from a Windows laptop to my router (Fritbox 7490) and need help to figure out **which "IPv4 address" I have enter in the respective fields while doing the setup, since "address" is obviously used for slightly different things in different tutorials,** including the AVM help pages:

- home-network internal IPv4 address
- IPv4 of a specific device, DHCP server etc.
- external/public (but temporary) IPv4
- Virtual IP adress displayd by Fritzbox for VPN user
- server-like address (xxxxxx.myfritz.net and xxxxxx.myfritz.net:xxxxxx), one of which directs to the current public IPv4.

I read plenty of information on IPv4, however I am confused by similar-sounding IPv4-(like-)entries and fields, and ask for clarification WHICH one to enter, since VPN does not work (I have to change settings at home, than go and find another wifi to test VPN). In order to clarify the different fields in Fritzboxsettuings, client on Windows and on Android, I named the fields A-H and wlk through them one by one.

According to the makers' (AVM) instruction, I have to change the IPv4 settings of my Fritzbox, so that the client (e.g. my laptop, possibly connected via a different Fritzbox somewhere else) and my own Fritzbox do not use the identical (default) IPv4 settings.

---

**1) on the router (accessed by browser):**

[image: Screenshot Fritzbox]

[image: myfritz.net]

(A) The dafault is 192.168.178.1, which is primarily the address that I have to change, correct? (default subnet 255.255.255.0)
I believe this is the (local) address of the router/DHCP server?

Via MyFritz.net I obtain a public/externally visible IPv4 address, which is different (D), presumably temporary, and a server-like address ("myfritz.net", and Fritzbox itselv gives me in addition "xxxxxxxxxx.myfritz.net:xxxxx") which presumably directs towards the temporary current external IPv4 of my Fritzbox.

B) This range of IPv4's here, I believe, is assigned to devices connected to the router. Why should this range be smaller than allowed by the network/subnet mask combination? What do I have to consider?

C) Local DNS server: is it correct, that it is always the same as A? Do I have to change that as well, why would it be a separate entry (unless I want to specify directly an external DNS server)?

Yet another "virtual IPv4 address" displayd by Fritzbox browser interface for the user with VPN assess rights, which is actually out of range of B.

---

**2) on Android:**

[image: Android]

(E) What do I have to enter as server address on Android: "xxxxxxxxxx.myfritz.net", "xxxxxxxxxx.myfritz.net:xxxxx")?

---

**3) on Windows, using the AVM recommended setup tool:**

[image: Windows]

Presumably I have NOT top use the manufacturer'ssettimgs (first radiobutton), but to use different settings (to avoid conflict of two defalut setting Fritzbooxes at home and the wifi hotspot)?

F) I believe this is the IPv4 network itself address here? Why would I enter a "private" IPv4 network? Even the "public" should be only temporary? No need for the server-like address from myfritz.net?

G) only one subset mask available which I cannot change, unlasse the last IPv4 address is 0 (which is not the case also in default settings - should I better use 0?).

H) What to enter ghere? "IP address of the user within the net of the (home) Fritzbox router" - ?

---

I appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do have a FritzBox and have successfully used the VPN feature of it (even though I don't like IPSec and won't recommend it).

Let me help you out by answering what the respective configuration options, you asked about, mean.

- A: This is the IP address of your FritzBox **in the local network**. Like any other device on your network, it needs an IP address and due to it being the DHCP server and gateway, it needs a static IP address. Just leave it default. You understood the MyFritz address correctly.
- B: This is correct, this is the DHCP range. You typically leave some space for static IP addresses (even though the FritzBox will take care of static IP addresses used in the configured range) and allows VPN clients to get their own addresses. Just leave it as is.
- C: This is the DNS server configuration that is sent via DHCP to all clients. You can override the DNS server, if you use a custom one, like a Pi-Hole or just want to directly go around your ISPs DNS servers (which is what your FritzBox will then redirect to by default).
- D: I don't know where this is from.
- E: In my experience, just using your myfritz address suffices here.
- F: A network is defined by its first IP address in its range. A single IP address is typically a /32 network with just this one host in it (and thus the network identifier and  broadcast are the same as the only IP address in it). Usually a network has a `0` as its last octet.
- G: I think this is already covered in F, but to answer your question: Yes, let your network end in `0`.
- H: This is the local IP address of the user, when connecting via VPN (IPSec). Your FritzBox should automatically assign you the first IP address beginning with `xxx.xxx.xxx.201`.

Comment: Thanks, but (point G): Ah, found it: F hasto be the x.x.x.0 NETWORK, NOT the Fritzbox address x.x.x.1 => then, it allows for 255.255.255.0 subnet masks, not only the /32 network, as a /32 network would not allow for the range (B) and the typical x.x.x.201 (H) address of the client on VPN.   
Sidenote: AVM explicitely ecommends to change IPv4 (A) in at least one of 2 Fritzboxes conected (e.g. home / friends), since 2x same default IPv4 will not work.